# Delta table as a stream source. How to calculate consumer lag

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am using apace spark structured streaming to stream the data from the delta table. The problem is that I have no visibility on consumer lag. How can we calculate consumer lag?

I have also gone throw the checkpoint files created per batch but that only has a timestamp in the epoch.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/delta-streaming#:~:text=for%20a%20stream-,Delta%20table%20as%20a%20stream%20source,and%20tables%20as%20a%20stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/delta-streaming#:%7E:text=for%20a%20stream-,Delta%20table%20as%20a%20stream%20source,and%20tables%20as%20a%20stream).

```
  .format("delta")
  .load("/mnt/delta/events")
  .groupBy("customerId")
  .count()
  .writeStream
  .format("delta")
  .outputMode("complete")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/mnt/delta/eventsByCustomer/_checkpoints/streaming-agg")
  .start("/mnt/delta/eventsByCustomer")
```

Comment: Did you check the stream progress logs? You have the latest offset for the delta source there. I am not sure it gives the lag, but maybe with the latest offset, you can query the source table and get the latest file for the latest version.